# iOS8 PhotoKit, some albums can't be finded

Tags: ios, objective-c, photokit

When I used PhotoKit to create my albums,there is not all albums in my project,some albums imported from computer can't be searched.I will post my code follow.

```
//get system albums
PHImageRequestOptions * options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.synchronous = YES;
KVPhotoAlbum * userAlum = nil;
PHCachingImageManager * manager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
PHFetchResult * systemAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];
for (id object in systemAlbums) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]]) {
        PHAssetCollection * collection = (PHAssetCollection*)object;
        if (collection.assetCollectionSubtype == PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos) {
            continue;   
        }
        //get photo
        PHFetchResult * imageResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
        if (imageResults.count) {
            KVPhotoAlbum * album = [[KVPhotoAlbum alloc] init];
            album.collection = collection;
            album.title = [collection valueForKey:@"localizedTitle"];
            album.photoCount = imageResults.count;
            if (collection.assetCollectionSubtype == PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary) {
                //camera
                userAlum = album;
            }else {
                [_albums addObject:album];
            }
            PHAsset * asset = [imageResults lastObject];
            [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60) contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                album.image = result;
            }];
        }
    }
}
//get albums created by user
PHFetchResult * customAlbums = [PHCollectionList fetchTopLevelUserCollectionsWithOptions:nil];
for (id object in customAlbums) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[PHAssetCollection class]]) {
        PHAssetCollection * collection = (PHAssetCollection*)object;
        if (collection.assetCollectionSubtype == PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumVideos) {
            continue;   
        }
        //get photo
        PHFetchResult * imageResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:nil];
        if (imageResults.count) {
            KVPhotoAlbum * album = [[KVPhotoAlbum alloc] init];
            album.collection = collection;
            album.title = [collection valueForKey:@"localizedTitle"];
            album.photoCount = imageResults.count;
            [_albums addObject:album];
            PHAsset * asset = [imageResults lastObject];
            [manager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:CGSizeMake(60, 60) contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                album.image = result;
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Too many code,I have to add more details.

Comment: Any body know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hello,anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself,now I show the way.
  There is a album type,"PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum",this can search these albums imported from computer.

```
PHFetchResult * importAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny options:nil];
```